# Cython compile error('lxml\includes.pxd' not found) with lxml and Jupyter notebook

Tags: lxml, cython

i have loaded Cython magic as(in my ipython notebook):

```
%load_ext Cython
```

above step was successful.

then i am referring "http://lxml.de/capi.html#writing-external-modules-in-cython"; in my ipython notebook as

```
%%cython

cimport etreepublic as cetree
cdef object etree
from lxml import etree
cetree.import_lxml__etree()
```

above step gives an error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...


cimport etreepublic as cetree
       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\swaga\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_c8f46d6a60c08cbbc40ceaeafaf39062.pyx:3:8: 'etreepublic.pxd' not found
```

then i have corrected it like:

```
%%cython


from lxml.includes cimport etreepublic as cetree
cdef object etree
from lxml import etree
cetree.import_lxml__etree()
```

now it is giving me error like:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...


from lxml.includes cimport etreepublic as cetree
^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\swaga\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_00532cf9159d976bfb24010b76ff3dfc.pyx:3:0: 'lxml\includes.pxd' not found
```

Other details:
lxml version is 3.4.4, Cython version 0.22 and Python is 2.7.9 [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

Edit: April- 2019
Cython Jupyter Lab Extension Arguments list is available at: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#compiling-with-a-jupyter-notebook

Comment: did you resolve that? I have the same problem

Comment: @Jusleong: I have added the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for `lxml` you are required to compile as `cpp`

in one notebook cell

```
import os
import lxml
def find_libxml2_include():
    include_dirs = []
    for d in ['/usr/include/libxml2', '/usr/local/include/libxml2']:
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(d, 'libxml/tree.h')):
            include_dirs.append(d)
    return include_dirs

for l in find_libxml2_include() + lxml.get_include():
    print("--include={0}".format(l))
```

It gives me:

```
--include=/usr/include/libxml2
--include=/home/nk/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml/includes
--include=/home/nk/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml
--include=/home/nk/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml/includes/__pycache__
```

Then another notebook cell where i will be using `lxml`:

```
%%cython --cplus --lib=xml2 --include=/usr/include/libxml2 --include=/home/nk/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml/includes --include=/home/nk/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml --include=/home/nk/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml/includes/__pycache__

from cpython.list cimport PyList_Append
from lxml.includes.etreepublic cimport _Element, _Document
cimport lxml.includes.etreepublic as cetree

cdef object etree

from lxml import etree
cetree.import_lxml__etree()

cdef bytes xmldoc

xmldoc = b"""<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Document>
    <Header>
        <Title>USEPA Geospatial Data</Title>
        <Creator>Environmental Protection Agency</Creator>
        <Subject>USEPA Geospatial Data</Subject>
        <Description>This XML file was produced by US EPA</Description>
        <Date>MAR-08-2013</Date>
    </Header>
    <Header>
        <Title>USEPA Geospatial Data</Title>
        <Creator>Environmental Protection Agency</Creator>
        <Subject>USEPA Geospatial Data</Subject>
        <Description>This XML file was produced by US EPA</Description>
        <Date>MAR-08-2013</Date>
    </Header>    
</Document>
"""

cdef void my_iterator(cetree._Document mydoc, cetree.tree.xmlNode* subnode, list result):
    cdef str tag
    cdef cetree.tree.xmlNode *node
    cdef cetree.tree.xmlNode *next_node

    if cetree.hasChild(subnode):
        node = cetree.findChild(subnode, 0)
    else:
        node = NULL

    while node != NULL:
        tag = cetree.namespacedName(node)
        PyList_Append(result, cetree.elementFactory(mydoc, node))
        my_iterator(mydoc, node, result)
        next_node = cetree.nextElement(node)
        node = next_node


cpdef test():
    cdef _Element e
    cdef list r
    e = etree.fromstring(xmldoc)
    r = []
    my_iterator(e._doc, e._c_node, r)
    for elem in r:
        print(elem)
    return e
```

Now, when i run `test` function:

```
>>> test()
<Element Header at 0x7fb370e4ab88>
<Element Title at 0x7fb370e7f7c8>
<Element Creator at 0x7fb370f13d08>
<Element Subject at 0x7fb370030848>
<Element Description at 0x7fb370030708>
<Element Date at 0x7fb370030748>
<Element Header at 0x7fb370f03148>
<Element Title at 0x7fb370f03588>
<Element Creator at 0x7fb370f03708>
<Element Subject at 0x7fb370603508>
<Element Description at 0x7fb370e8abc8>
<Element Date at 0x7fb370e8ab08>
```